# Listening Map Event Using Google Map in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I have a problem when I try to apply Google Maps on vue js.
My problem is when listening to an event when drawing a pin and dragging it. When the pin is clicked the coordinate value will be seen in the LatLng textbox, then after the pin is shifted the value in the textbox will change automatically without needing to click first.

here is a snippet of my program

```
<template>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Location</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <google-map-loader :map-config="mapConfig" :map-center="'Bali'">
                        <template slot-scope="{google, map}">
                            <google-map-drawing-manager
                                    :google="google"
                                    :map="map"
                                    :drawing-modes="['marker']"
                                    :marker-options="markerOptions"
                                    :control="true">
                                {{drawingManagerListener}}
                            </google-map-drawing-manager>
                        </template>
                    </google-map-loader>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-3">Latitude</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" v-model="latitude" class="form-control">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-3">Longitude</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" v-model="longitude" class="form-control">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-success"><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'save']" /> Simpan</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-danger"><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'times-circle']" /> Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {EventBus} from "../../../utils/event-bus";
    import GoogleMapLoader from "../../../components/maps/GoogleMapLoader";
    import { mapSettings } from "../../../utils/mapSettings";

    import GoogleMapDrawingManager from "../../../components/maps/GoogleMapDrawingManager";

    export default {
        components: {
            GoogleMapDrawingManager, GoogleMapLoader
        },
        data() {
            return {
                latitude: '',
                longitude: '',
            }
        },

        computed: {
            mapConfig() {
                return {
                    ...mapSettings
                };
            },
            markerOptions(){
                return {
                    draggable: true
                }
            },
            drawingManagerListener() {
                EventBus.$on('drawingManager',drawingManager => {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'markercomplete', function (marker) {
                        marker.addListener('click', function (coords) {
                            EventBus.$emit('coords', coords);
                        });

                        marker.addListener('rightclick', function (event) {
                            marker.setMap(null);
                        });
                    });

                });
                EventBus.$on('coords', coords => {
                    this.latitude = coords.latLng.lat();
                    this.longitude = coords.latLng.lng();
                });
            },

        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The code above is able to run it's just that the obstacles when dragging a pin, the value in the textbox does not change automatically. I hope you understand of what i mean and be able to solve my problem.

Thank You

Comment: What about adding the right listener?? You added a listener for click and right-click. I see no listener for drag or drag-end or whatever else.

Comment: @MrUpsidown the problem was solved, i forgot to add a 'dragend' to the marker event listener

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add 'dragend' event listener to the marker.

```
drawingManagerListener() {
            EventBus.$on('drawingManager',drawingManager => {
                google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'markercomplete', function (marker) {
                    marker.addListener('click', function (coords) {
                        EventBus.$emit('coords', coords);
                    });

                    marker.addListener('dragend', function (event) {
                        EventBus.$emit('coords', coords);
                    });

                    marker.addListener('rightclick', function (event) {
                        marker.setMap(null);
                    });
                });

            });
            EventBus.$on('coords', coords => {
                this.latitude = coords.latLng.lat();
                this.longitude = coords.latLng.lng();
            });
        },
```

so with the code i can handle the event when i click and drag the marker.